# Postgres: calculate the percentage of successful events per day of week

Tags: postgresql

For each city in my dataset and each day of the week, I need to determine the percentage of signups in the first week of 2016 that resulted in a completed trip within 168 hours of the sign up date.

So far I can calculate the overall percentage for each city with

```
select cities.city_name, round( 100.0 * (sum(case when event_name='sign_up_success' then 1 end)) / count(events), 2) as percent from
trips inner join events on
trips.client_id = events.rider_id inner join cities on
trips.city_id = cities.city_id
group by city_name;
```

however, when I try to add a `over (partition by date_trunc('day', event._ts))` clause the error states `round` cannot be used as a aggregate or window function.

The closest I am able to get is the following,

```
select cities.city_name, 
      round( 100.0 * (sum(case when event_name='sign_up_success' then 1 end)) / count(events), 2) as percent 
from  trips 
inner join events 
   on trips.client_id = events.rider_id 
inner join cities 
   on  trips.city_id = cities.city_id
where trips.status = 'completed' 
  and events._ts < '2016-01-08' 
  and (trips.request_at - events._ts) < interval '168 hours'
group by cities.city_name;
```

How can I extend this such that the percentage of completed trips is calculated per day? e.g.

```
Day  | City_1 | City_2
 1   | 45     | 25
 2   | 0      | 66
 3   | 100    | 25
 4   | 45     | 75
etc
```

Comment: can you post sample data to generate that output?

Comment: `in the first week of 2016` why only first week?

Comment: Can there be more than 2 cities? An unlimited number? And you want each city to have its own column?

Comment: @DavidAman yes, technically there could be more than 2 cities, but i'm only concerned with 2. I can add a constraint for `city_name` as well.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza my analysis is only concerned with the first week around new years. i'll post the schema.

Comment: then why is `'2016-01-08'`  there?,

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza to limit the data returned to only the first seven days of 2016.

Comment: Bumping this up. Can someone provide the solution. The problem looks interesting and I'm unable to get the solution

Comment: @idclark there is no events._ts timestamp in events table